# Setting a default value in input tag

Tags: php, html

I want to set a default value in a input tag which is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $field['name']; ?>" id="ticket_<?php echo $field['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" <?php if( isset( $field['required'] ) ): ?>required<?php endif;?>readonly>
```

When I keep the readonly then the default value is displayed, but when I remove the readonly then the default value is not set and vanishes.

Comment: Using readonly should not have any bearing on the input keeping its default value.

Comment: I don't know why it is happening but when I remove the readonly the dedault value vanishes and is not displayed.

Comment: Is there a way that you can demonstrate this to us? We have no way of replicating your issue.

Comment: You should have tried basic debugging yourself before asking this question. For starters, figure out if your mistake lies in PHP or HTML; just look at the HTML output from your script and see if it looks the way you expect. If it does, post a question with the HTML and leave out the PHP. If not, figure out what aspect of your PHP's behaviour is unexpected and ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

Readonly attribute has no affect on value attribute.

But there is no space between required and readonly attributes.

You have to set default value if the $val is empty or not set.

try this:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $field['name']; ?>" id="ticket_<?php echo $field['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo (!empty($var) ? $var : ''); ?>" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" <?php if( isset( $field['required'] ) ): ?>required<?php endif;?> readonly>
```

Comment: If you include a value attribute and do not set it it will be blank automatically. The readonly or required properties would have no affect on the value.

Comment: I know that $var is not empty because just when I again enter the readonly and refresh page the value gets displayed while if I remove the readonly then the value disappears.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm trying to tell him a possible php error / notice would cause a problem. If $val is not set and php throws a notice about that. And if you don't give a space between two attributes, they are not attributes anymore.

Comment: I understand that @R.CanserYanbakan, but what you are saying does not answer the OP's question. The OP says that the value attribute is set properly when he includes readonly, and not set when it doesn't. That means that $var is set properly (not throwing a notice).

Comment: Even a hardcoded value is not visible in this textfield.
for e.g. if I put value = "var" then also it is not seen.

Comment: @user2168945 Let's make a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FdVqy/ see? i'm talking about this. I don't think your value is defined... Why isn't working then?

Comment: The hard coded values appear in both inputs on the jsfiddle regardless of the state of the readonly and required properties. It's too bad that PHP fiddle isn't working right now. My guess is that you have a typo somewhere in your PHP code.

Comment: @user2168945 Just to be sure, please send the rest of your code where you define that $var, $class and $field variables.